# Create highlight group that modifies an existing one

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plugin-coc

I would like to create a new highlighting group that is exactly like an existing one except for one (or more) properties. For example, the new group could be an underlined version of the existing one.

Context: I'm using [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and its [semantic highlighting](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/80276faf96fe80c2908aa4c46e08289dad97d432/doc/coc.txt#L2980) feature. To support the language server protocol's token modifiers, coc.nvim creates combined highlighting groups. For example, `CocSemVariable` for immutable variables, and `CocSemMutableVariable` for mutable ones. What I would like to do is something like this:

```
highlight! link CocSemMutableVariable CocSemVariable
highlight! CocSemMutableVariable cterm=underline gui=underline
```

This doesn't work however since any `highlight` command [will break links](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight-link). Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this directly with `highlight!` since links and groups are fundamentally different.  You can have a highlight that is a link or a highlight with properties, you can't have both.

Instead you can try to use `hlget` and `hlset` as follows:

```
let resolve = v:true   " set to v:false if not wanting to resolve links

let hl = hlget('CocSemVariable', resolve)[0]
let hl.name = 'CocSemMutableVariable'
let hl.cterm = {'underline': v:true}
let hl.gui = {'underline': v:true}
call hlset([hl])
```

Of course, this is not a real link and vim is not blending anything.  If you modify `CocSemVariable`, these changes will not appear in `CocSemMutableVariable`.  You can mitigate this to some extent via

```
function! Tweaks()
   ... code from above ...
endfunction
au ColorScheme * call Tweaks()
```

So that when groups are changed through changing colorschemes (the usual situation), the dependent groups are automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks, this could do what I want! `hlget` and `hlset` seem to be quite recent, however, and my Vim doesn't have the required [patch](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/d1a8d658e1b16cf8579fc72cf7aa6a29a57ff5ef) yet. I will try to install a newer version tomorrow.

Comment: One question: does this work if `CocSemVariable` is itself a link? Or would I need to follow the link(s) manually somehow?

Comment: I just updated the answer, there's an argument to hlget that will work if it is a link.

Also if you don't have `hlget`, you could theoretically do this with e.g., `synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID('CocSemVariable')), 'fg', 'gui')` but it is a lot more effort.

Comment: Thanks, I almost got this to work. The problem now seems to be that my color scheme defines the thing that `CocSemVariable` links to in `after/syntax` which seems to be called after the `ColorScheme` `autocmd`. So `hlget` returns a `cleared` highlight group. Is there another place to call `Tweak` to ensure it always comes last?